# Cant run commands in terminal magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cli, file-permissions

When try run command in terminal example 
**`php bin setup:upgrade`** 
show like these error messages. Not only that but also all commands

> -[ReflectionException]
>       Class Magento\Config\Console\Command\ConfigSet\ProcessorFacadeFactory does
>   not exist.
>   - [ReflectionException]
>       Class Magento\Config\Console\Command\ConfigSet\ProcessorFacadeFactory does
>   not exist.
>   - [RuntimeException]
>       Can't create directory /var/www/html/robolk/generated/code/Magento/Config/Console/Command/ConfigSet/.
>   in [Magento\Config\Console\Command\ConfigSet\ProcessorFacadeFactory].

Why is Magento showing these errors?

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Where is Magento showing these errors for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to Set permission in Var like ...

```
Sudo chmod 0777 -R var/ generated/
```

If sudo not working then just ..

```
chmod 0777 -R var/ generated/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on Magento 2.2+ which has generated folder on root

so for that you have to give 0777 permission to 3 folders

pub, var, generated

chmod 0777 -R var/ generated/ pub/

Also you need to check that server user has enough permission to create files and folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide **`777`** or **`775`** **file/folder** permission to

> **var** and **pub** and **generated**

That is

**`sudo chmod 0777 -R var/ pub/ generated/`** if you have sudo access

if have normal access then

**`chmod 0777 -R var/ pub/ generated/`**

**directory** for your **webserver user** (like apache) and the **current user of CLI** both

Comment: I gave but still problem is same

Comment: which command you try to run

Comment: 777 file permission

Comment: sudo chmod 777 -R

Comment: ok you provide permission for both var and pub directory
Now can you let me know which magento command you try to run